# Estimate a sum using proportional sampling

Tags: estimation, mean, estimators

I have some set of items. Each item has a weight and I can sample the items from the population with probabilities proportional to their weights. I know the size of the population. I want to estimate the total/average weight of the population. The population is assumed to be finite.

What is known about this problem? Could you please give me some pointers to the literature?

Comment: Stephen Thompson, *Sampling;* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horvitz%E2%80%93Thompson_estimator.  (You already know about the latter: you asked about it in your previous, now deleted, question.)

Comment: Thank you for the reference. Could you elaborate on how it helps? I think I cannot use that when I don't know the probabilities which I don't as otherwise, I would also know the sum.

Comment: Your question indicates you *do* know the weights, so please clarify that.

Comment: Yes, I do know the weights, I don't know the probabilities. These differ by a factor given by the sum I am trying to estimate.

Comment: Since the probabilities must sum to unity, you can easily compute them from the weights.

Comment: Yes, by dividing by the total. However, I don't know that.

Comment: You lost me: now you have twice implied you know the weights and twice implied you don't!  Could you perhaps just describe the problem you actually have?

Comment: I have described it, this is the problem. And no, I have twice implied I do know the weights and twice that I don't know the probabilities. Knowing one is not the same as knowing the other.

Comment: How are you sampling?  With replacement?

Comment: Yes, independent samples

Answer (score 0):

So you have a distribution of numbers (interpreted as weights) and you want to estimate the mean of the population? A very well studied problem!

The mean of the sample is an unbiased estimate of the mean of the distribution. However, it is not robust - one outlier can throw out the estimate. How much of a problem this is in practice depends on the variance. If the distribution is normal, with a standard deviation that is small compared to the mean, the estimator will be good. If the distribution has "Black Swans" (rare extreme values) then you are in trouble.

Comment: The mean of a *probability weighted* sample is a *biased* estimate, I'm afraid.  You might have overlooked some crucial details in the question.